# add code to move each byte of i1 into the unsigned chars c1 through c4 with the high order byte going into c1 and the low order into c4

Tags: c++

Inside the block denoted by the **_asm** keyword, add code to move each byte of i1 into the unsigned chars c1 through c4 with the high order byte going into c1 and the low order into c4.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void main ()
            {
            unsigned char c1;
            unsigned char c2;
            unsigned char c3;
            unsigned char c4;
            unsigned long i1 (0xaabbccee);

            _asm
                        {
                        }

            cout.flags (ios::hex);
            cout << "results are " << (unsigned int) c1 << ", "
                                                << (unsigned int) c2 << ", "
                                                << (unsigned int) c3 << ", "
                                                << (unsigned int) c4 << endl;
            }
```

Comment: If you want help with assembly you might want to tag it as assembly

Comment: @Shashank,  welcome to stackoverflow. What is your question ? what issue are you having. Your question needs to be concise and direct, so it can attract answers. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This question should have been put on hold a year ago. I will try to do so now.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it in `c++` here is a way. To use `_asm` you might want to tag the question as such. You can use bit masking such that:

```cpp
unsigned char c1, c2, c3, c4;
unsigned long long i1;
c1 = 0xFF & (i1 >> 24);
c2 = 0xFF & (i1 >> 16);
c3 = 0xFF & (i1 >> 8);
c4 = 0xFF & i1;
```

you can also automate this if you need to, to work with other arithmetic types:

```cpp
template <typename T>
std::vector<unsigned char> getBits(T data){
    std::vector<unsigned char> ret;
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(T); i++)
        ret.push_back(0xFF & (data >> i*8));
    return ret;
}
```

Technically you can omit `0xFF &` in both examples, as the type will implicitly do that when casting.

With inline assembly in `g++` you can do this via something like:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    unsigned char c1, c2, c3, c4;
    unsigned long long i1(0xaabbccee);
    asm(R"(
        .intel_syntax noprefix
        mov rax, %[i1]
        mov %[c4], al
        shr rax, 8
        mov %[c3], al
        shr rax, 8
        mov %[c2], al
        shr rax, 8
        mov %[c1], al
        .att_syntax
)"
        : [c1] "=r" (c1), [c2] "=r" (c2), [c3] "=r" (c3), [c4] "=r" (c4)
        : [i1] "r"(i1)
        : "rax");

    std::cout
    << (unsigned int) c1 << " "
    << (unsigned int) c2 << " "
    << (unsigned int) c3 << " "
    << (unsigned int) c4 << " ";

    return 0;
}
```

This is a bit different from how you wanted to but I have no idea how other compilers do it (I barely have an idea how `gcc` does it), but I hope this can be of some help. Also I assumed `x86_64` as the architecture, hence `rax`.

Comment: `sizeof(unsigned char)` for a byte's *bit size*?  Don't you mean [`CHAR_BIT`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/climits) from `<climit>`?

Comment: @Eljay Sorry I messed up thanks for that. Forgot sizeof returns bytes